# C++ Moving By Reference, values doesn't change?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I wrote the following method in my `tree` class:

```
public:
    node<T> *root;

template<class T>
node<T> *tree<T>::insert(node<T> *p, const T &key) {
    if (p == nullptr) {
       p = new node<T>(key);
    }
    //Some code
}
```

But I have noticed that even though the if condition gets executed the value of the tree root doesn't change, what is causing this behaviour?

This is how my call looks like in `main.cpp`:

```
tree<int> t1{};
t1.insert(t1.root,7);
```

It's clear that I am moving by reference and not by value since I gave insert a pointer to the root's node. (root is a pointer to the root)

I hope someone can clearly explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this since I'm stuck on this one for a day.

Comment: Parameter `p` is passed by value; in effect, it's a copy of `t1.root`. Changes to this parameter within the function are not visible to the caller.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik why by value it's a pointer

Comment: @user128250 pointers are values too. There is no special rule for pointers that says they aren't passed as values (this is an extremely common misunderstanding).

Comment: even if pointer is copied by value still it has the same inner value (points to the same object)

Comment: Consider: `int a=0, b=1; int* p = &a; void f(int* q) { *q = 42; q = &b; } f(p);` After the `f(p)` call, `a == 42`, but `p` still points to `a`, not to `b`. Yes, you pass a pointer to the function. What you change **through** that pointer is visible to the caller; but change to the pointer itself is not.

Comment: @user128250 You are making the same mistake that many newbies make about pointers. The pointer, and what it is pointing to are not the same thing. If your function was changing what `p` is pointing to then you would see that change outside the function. But you are not doing that, you are changing **the pointer itself**, and that change is not visible outside the function, because of the copy that I've already explained.

Comment: @user128250 It's really simple, it's just that newbies have a habit of over complicating things. I'm sure you can agree you have two variables `p` and `root`, and you change one of them with `p = ...`. Why should that change the other variable? Would it change the other variable if they were both integers? Why should it be any different for pointers? The truth is that it isn't any different for pointers.

Comment: @user128250 Rereading your post above it's clear you have a good understanding. The only error is your insistance (you say it quite explicitly) that pointers are passed by reference. That's not true, and if you can drop that msunderstanding I'm sure it will click.

Answer (score 2):

Because `p` is not `root`. Calling your `insert` function with root as the parameter **copies** that pointer to `p`, it doesn't make `p` the same variable as `root`. So changes to `p` have no effect on `root`.

If you want to make is so `p` is the same variable as `root` then you must use a reference

```
template<class T>
node<T> *tree<T>::insert(node<T> *&p, const T &key) {
```

Now the pointer `p` is a reference to whatever pointer was used to call `insert`, so changes to `p` will change that original pointer (`root` in your case).

Comment: But I don't understand why, I send a pointer to the root and save it into p, what is wrong with this?

Comment: Plus, If we suppose that p is copied by value it is a pointer and that doesn't matter since still it will point to the same thing when acessed

Comment: @user128250 But (and this is the crucial thing) you aren't changing what is it pointing to, you are changing the pointer itself.

Comment: You don't send a pointer to the root. `root` itself is a pointer to some `Node<T>`. You never pass a pointer to `root`. You also never change the contents of what `p` is pointed to, you just change what `p` points to.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `t1.root` by value, not by reference or by pointer. Therefore, the function `insert` gets its own copy of the variable `t1.root`, and changing this copy does not change the original variable.

To solve this problem, you can either pass by reference or by pointer, instead of passing by value.

In order to pass by pointer, you could change the function `insert` to the following:

```
node<T> *tree<T>::insert(node<T> **pp, const T &key) {
    if (*pp == nullptr) {
       *pp = new node<T>(key);
    }
    //Some code
}
```

The first parameter of the function is now a pointer to a pointer, i.e. a double pointer. In order to get the pointer from the double pointer, you must dereference it once using `*`.

When calling the function, you must also add a `&` (address-of-operator) to `t1.root`, like this:

```
t1.insert(&t1.root,7);
```

That way, you will be passing the address of `t1.root`, so that the function can modify the original value.

Alternatively, you can pass `t1.root` by reference, like this:

```
node<T> *tree<T>::insert(node<T> *&p, const T &key) {
    if (p == nullptr) {
       p = new node<T>(key);
    }
    //Some code
}
```

In that case, you don't have to add the `&` in front of `t1.root` when calling the function, and you also don't have to use `*` for dereferencing in the function body. It is effectively the same thing as using a double pointer, but C++ handles the dereferencing and passing the address for you, so you don't have to worry about it.